# A function that determines the approximate root

Tags: java

The code below calculates the approximate root of the equation f (x) = 0 in the interval [a, b] with precision E.
However, I want the data to be entered by the user in the In.txt file

Example [In.txt]
-1 5 0.25 (x*x)-2 // [a,b]=[-1,5], E=0.25

Example [Out.txt]
1.4375

```
class xyz {
    static final float EPSILON = (float) 0.25;
    static double func(double x) {
        return x * x - 2;
    }


    static void bisection(double a, double b) {
        if (func(a) * func(b) >= 0) {
            System.out.println("You have not assumed" +
                    " right a and b");
            return;
        }

        double c = a;
        while ((b - a) >= EPSILON) {

            c = (a + b) / 2;


            if (func(c) == 0.0)
                break;


            else if (func(c) * func(a) < 0)
                b = c;
            else
                a = c;
        }

        System.out.printf("The value of root is : %.4f", c);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double a = -1, b = 5;
        bisection(a, b);
    }

}
```

The problem, however, is code transformation. I know I am doing it wrong, but I have no idea how to properly fix this problem.

```
class xyz {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("In.txt");
        PrintWriter save = new PrintWriter("Out.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        double a = in.nextDouble();
        double b = in.nextFloat();
        float epsilon = in.nextFloat();
        double func = in.nextDouble();
    }


   void bisection(double a, double b) {
        if (func(a) * func(b) >= 0) {
            System.out.println("You have not assumed" +
                    " right a and b");
            return;
        }

        double c = a;
        while ((b - a) >= epsilon) {

            c = (a + b) / 2;


            if (func(c) == 0.0)
                break;


            else if (func(c) * func(a) < 0)
                b = c;
            else
                a = c;
        }

        save.println("The value of root is : %.4f", c);

    }

    save.close();


    }
```

Comment: Two issues:  Your `main` is reading values, but then never calling `bisect`.  I should also mention that your definition of `bisect` is will only work if function is `func(a) > 0 > func(b)`.  It won't work if `func(a) < 0 < func(b)`.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that you want to write a Java program that reads a text file with a line containing a string like `f(x)=(x*x)-2` and then your program would transform that into Java code like `double f(double x) { return (x*x)-2; }` and then be able to execute that function?

Comment: @Andrew Merrill All in all, it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: Check quake 3 fast inverse square root

Comment: I do not understand..

Comment: You may need a math express parser library like [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/). PS: I haven't used it, just for an example.